# Como puedo filtrar un campo que esta relacionado con otra tabla

Tags: laravel-8

necesito de su ayuda. Necesito filtrar un campo user_id pero que lo pueda filtrar escribiendo el nombre y no el id, tengo una relación de usuarios con pos de uno a muchos.

```
//relacion uno a muchos User con Post
public function posts(){

    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

En mi controlador tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
$posts = Post::where('id', '>=', '1')
                    ->where('name', 'LIKE','%'. $this->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE','%'. $this->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('user_id', 'LIKE','%'. $this->search . '%')
                    ->latest('id')
                    ->paginate(8);
```

Me funciona pero quisera que me buscara por nombre del author del post, y no por el id del usuario que creo el post.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que en el modelo `Post` tienes una relación `belongsTo` que relaciona un post con un solo usuario. Suponiendo que esa relación se llama `author`, podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
$search = $this->search;
        
$posts = Post::where('id', '>=', '1')
                ->where('name', 'LIKE','%'. $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE','%'. $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('user_id', 'LIKE','%'. $search . '%')
                ->orWhereHas('author', function($query) use ($search) {
                    $query->where('name', $search);
                })
                ->latest('id')
                ->paginate(8);
```

[Aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) puedes encontrar la documentación relacionada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó perfecto.

Answer (score -1):

Gracias amigo me funcionó perfecto. Así quedó.

```
$search = $this->search;
    
    $posts = Post::where('id', '>=', '1')
                    ->where('name', 'LIKE','%'. $this->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE','%'. $this->search . '%')
                    
                    ->orWhereHas('user', function($query) use ($search) {
                        $query->where('name', 'LIKE','%'. $search . '%');
                        $query->orWhere('email', 'LIKE','%'. $search . '%');
                    })
                    ->orWhereHas('category', function($query) use ($search) {
                        $query->where('name', 'LIKE','%'. $search . '%');
                        
                    })
                    ->latest('id')
                    ->paginate(8);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [answer] y a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas un poco más el funcionamiento de Stack Overflow. Tu respuesta parece más un comentario.

Comment: Si tenes una respuesta que te funciono, no es necesario que agregues otra respuesta. Acepta la respuesta que te funciono. Esa es la forma de decir gracias.

Comment: Cómo la acepto?